# shuttle xs35v2 - can't boot from usb drive

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb-drive, lubuntu

I'am trying to install lubuntu on a new shuttle barebone xs35v2.
I have tryed with various usb-sticks and diffrent versions, e.g: lubuntu-net installer, lubuntu 62 and 32, and standart ubuntu-version!
**I have used a macbook with the unetbootin-app to make the usb-boot-drive.**

the bios is showing my flash-drive and i set the correct boot-order.
Is this maschine not able to boot from a usb-drive?

I realy don't know what to try/do anymore.

Thanks in advance for any help.

(Chip: Atom D525 with 500gb and 4gb ram, no cd-rom)

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB stick? Please [edit] your question to include this information; do not add it as a comment.

Comment: @roaima i have marked how i have formatet the drive. thanks - ok?

Comment: Does the USB stick you've created boot on any other PC or laptop? (You don't need to install; just confirm that the boot succeeds.)

Comment: @roaima i only have apple gear. it is a problem as far as i know. give me second to try it.

Comment: the usb drives i tested are older ones: usb1 or 2 and one test with a new stick that is usb-3.0. so that should not be the error-source

Comment: Unfortunately _should_ is not a useful word here. We need to partition the problem: either the USB stick / image is at fault or the Shuttle hasn't correctly been told to boot from it. If you can eliminate one of these options it would help tremendously.

Comment: @roaima i can boot the usb drive that i created first (lubuntu 15.04 - 64bit with a verified hash-sequence) on my macbook without a problem, it list's it and then it runs. i also tried some settings in the bios (on the shuttle barebone) but there a not many options to set. do you have a other idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28797/discussion-between-stevethemechanic-and-roaima).

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question here.

I have now createt a bootable usb-stick with the os x shell. Over on tutsplus is a good tutorial, that walks trough the steps to create a pc-bootable ubuntu-stick with os x, it works the same way with lubuntu or other linux flavours. The netbootin app on os x seems not ready to create a working usb-stick, but funny enough that you can boot it on os x yosemite but not on a intel-chip shuttle (xs35v2).

Good luck if you runn in the same troubles.